# Python: Package install error

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I have some problems with python 3 module installing. I'm trying to install mysql using pip :

```
   pip install mysqlclient
```

for python 2.7 and here is the error I get:

error: command 'C:\Users\RAVI TEJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

My specs : Windows 10 x64

Python 2.7

Comment: so are you installing for python3 or 2 ? pip installs for python 2.X

Comment: I am trying to install it for python 2.7

Comment: Can you post full error that pip gives